# ¿Cómo convertir un dato de tipo string en int en una biblioteca de clases?

Tags: c#

Estoy empezando dos [ABM](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRUD), uno para alumnos y otro para países en `aspx.net` y no se como hacer para convertir el documento y la fecha de nacimiento de `string` y `datatime` a `int`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Libreria_del_ABM
{
    public class Alumnos
    {
        private string _nombre;
        private string _apellido;
        private string _documento;
        private DateTime _fechadenacimiento;
        private string _nacionalidad;            

        public Alumnos()
        {
            this.Nombre = "pepito";
            this.Apellido = "perez";
            this.Documento = 39491453;
            this.Fechadenacimiento = 23 / 12 / 1995;
            this.Nacionalidad = "peruano";
        }

        public string Nombre
        {
            get => _nombre;
            set => _nombre = value;    
        }

        public string Apellido
        {
            get => _apellido;
            set => _apellido = value;    
        }

        public int Documento    
        {
            get => _documento;
            set => _documento = value;
        }

        public DateTime Fechadenacimiento
        {
            get => _fechadenacimiento;
            set => _fechadenacimiento = value;
        }

        public string Nacionalidad
        {
            get => _nacionalidad;
            set => _nacionalidad = value;
        }

        public string alumnoinscripto()
        {
            return "El alumno" + this.Nombre + this.Apellido 
                   + "D.N.I " + this.Documento;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Para convertir de string a int puedes usar dos funciones

`Int32.Parse`

```
string texto = "123124124";
int numero = Int32.Parse(texto);
```

o `Int32.TryParse` la cual no genera un error en caso de que la conversión falle como si lo haría `Int32.Parse`

```
string texto = "no tengo numeros";
int numero = 0;
Int32.TryParse(texto, out numero)
```

Dependiendo a lo que te refieras por convertir la fecha a numero hay varias opciones

1. Usando `DateTime.Ticks` la cual convierte la fecha a nanosegundos desde el 1 de enero del 0001
2. usando `DateTime.ToString(formato);` donde formato puede ser `"yyyyMMdd"` donde se indica el ano, el mes, el dia y luego convirtiendo la string resultado de la conversion a numero con uno de los metodos previamente mencionados.

Answer (score 0):

Para asignar una fecha podrias usar

```
this.Fechadenacimiento = Convert.ToDataTime("23/12/1995");
```

Nota: en este caso recuerda validar que cultura estas utilizando ya que si es En-us el formato deberia ser MM/dd/yyyy, o sea va primero el mes y luego el dia

Tambien podrias usar

```
this.Fechadenacimiento = new DateTime(1995, 12, 23);
```

Para asignar el numeroco es similar

```
this.Documento = Convert.ToInt32("39491453");
```

si es que tienes el numero como string

Por otro lado tu codigo se podrias reducir mucho si defeines las propiedades de esta forma

```
public class Alumnos
{

    public Alumnos()
    {
        this.Nombre = "pepito";
        this.Apellido = "perez";
        this.Documento = 39491453;
        this.Fechadenacimiento = 23 / 12 / 1995;
        this.Nacionalidad = "peruano";
    }

    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Apellido { get; set; }

    //otras propiedades

}
```

No necesitas las variables privadas ni tampoco indicar el get y set